# Организация работы модемов

Tags: архитектура, java

Клиент-серверное приложение. Есть несколько модемов, подключенных к серверу. Клиент через API может совершать звонки и отправлять sms. Естественно клиентов одновременно может быть несколько, которые работают одновременно, так же как и модемы.
Может кто-нить сталкивался с подобной задачей? Меня интересует только архитектура приложения, а именно диаграмма классов. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Это делается очень просто. Но тут есть некоторые тонкости, которые мне неизвестны (неизвестны точные требования). Но мне видится три пути. Вы делаете некий ModemManager (пул модемов), который позволяет взять "свободный" модем и вернуть его обратно. А дальше варианты:

1. Делаете пул потоков (ExecutorService) размером в количество модемов и запускаете диспетчер задач. Делаете ArrayBlockingQueue и каждый раз, когда надо что-то отправить, все пользовали ломятся в эту queue. Далее, диспетчер достаёт из неё с помощью блокирующей операции take и запускает задачу в пуле на выполнение.
2. Делаете пул потоков фиксированного размера (по количеству модемов). Каждый раз, когда клиент хочет что-то сделать, он запускает задачу в пуле и получает Future.. так что он сможет отслеживать ход выполнения.
3. Нечто среднее между 1 и 2. Делаете любой пул и запускаете на пуле долгоиграющие Runnable заранее каждому из них выдав по модему. Делаете блокирующую Queue и все обработчики модемов делают take для очереди, так что они спят когда нет задач. Все клиенты кладут задачи в эту queue. Долгоиграющие задачи будут постепенно брать задачи из очереди и выполнять их (каждый на своём модеме).

Каждый из трёх методов имеет свои преимущества и свои недостатки. Понятно, что в первом и в третьем придётся делать дополнительную работу, по уведомлению клиентов о том, что задача выполнена. Хотя во втором это также не исключено. Второй имеет преимущество в том, что пул реально может уничтожать ненужные потоки, если работы мало, тогда как первый и третий всегда держит столько потоков, сколько модемов. Хотя, если работы мало, то они все спят, а если много, то тогда разницы нет. Так что по большому счёту разница между этими вариантами непринципиальна. Но лично я склоняюсь к третьему варианту (логика в ModemManager минимальна, так как модемы расперделены между воркерами в момент запуска и можно добавлятьудалять их по горячему). Кроме того, первый и последний вариант имеют ещё одно преимущество: вы можете приоретизировать задачи, используя, например, PriorityBlockingQueue, тогда как во втором случае вы не сможете это делать.